# Single subject anova

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, sample-size

I collected walking speed data over 2 weeks for a single subject. These different walking speed were separated into 7 different groups based on whether they were extracted during a shorter or longer walk. I would like to determine whether the mean and the variance of walking speeds from the different groups are different. I am unsure which statistical test is appropriate as I have only one subject. (also, the sample size in each group is different, going from 199 to 1093 values of walking speed...)
Thank you.

Comment: Having a single subject will not affect the test you should perform. It's just that the population that your result will generalize to, is walking speeds of that one person. Would be helpful if you add the following information: Are the collected walking speeds dependent in any other way? E.g., collected during the same walk? This would require a mixed-effects model to account for that. How are the longer and shorter walk groups defined? It is currently unclear if it is a categorical or continuous predictor.

Comment: Assuming a categorical grouping of walk-lengths, and no additional dependence structure, you can use a one-way ANOVA to test for equality of means between the groups (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance), and Levene's test (https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toets_van_Levene) to test for equality of variances between the groups. Unequal sample sizes will lower the power of the statistical tests, but I would not be too worried about that with such large sample sizes.

Comment: @MarjoleinFokkema Thank you for these answers. To clarify, I have separate walking bouts that each contain walking speeds. I classify each walking bout using their length meaning group 1 is bouts between 0-5min and group 7 is bouts between 20+ minutes. and then everything in between. So in each group it is speed for a different walk.

Comment: Does one bout yield multiple walking speed measurements, or only one?

Comment: One bout yield multiple walking speed measurements. So, the person walked for 2 weeks. I isolated their walking bouts. I classified each bout within the duration categories mentioned above. Then within each bout, I calculate the walking speed of each strides, so long bouts yield a great amount of walking speed values, whereas small walking bouts only have a couple of strides in them. So each category has a number of walking bout, and each bout has a certain number of walking speed values. I hope I am making this a little clearer...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have data with a nested structure: Some of the response values were obtained in the same bout. This may cause dependence between values observed within the same bout, which can be accounted for using a mixed-effect model.

I assume you are using **`R`** and have variables similar to the following in your dataset (`dat`): `group` (factor; predictor), `speed` (continuous; response), `bout` (factor; cluster identifier)

You can test for equality of means as follows:

```
library("nlme")
mod <- lme(speed ~ group, random = ~1|bout, data = dat)
anova(mod)
VarCorr(mod)
```

The last rule is to check on the dependence within bouts. Higher values for the `(Intercept)` term indicate stronger dependence within bouts.

You can test for equality of variances as follows:

```
library("car")
leveneTest(residuals(mod) ~ dat$bout)
```

Perhaps unnecessary to add, but I would do a visual inspection of the data beforehand:

```
boxplot(speed ~ group + bout, data = dat)
```

or:

```
boxplot(speed ~ bout, data = dat) 
boxplot(speed ~ group, data = dat)
```

This will also help identify which groups differ, if any of the F-tests come out significant.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful!

Comment: @Lou You're welcome!